# Calling a function usingTouchableHighlight with onPress throwing error "[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onPressCalenderView]"

Tags: android, react-native, react-calendar

render() {
return (
<TouchableHighlightonPress= {this.onPressCalenderView}>
<Text style={{color:'black', fontSize:20}}>dd/mm/yyyy</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
)
};

```
 onPressCalenderView = async () => {
  try {
    this.setState({showCalendarView: true});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
 };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <TouchableHighlight onPress= {this.onPressCalenderView}>
<Text style={{color:'black', fontSize:20}}>dd/mm/yyyy</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>